# Is it possible to have terminal make a sound when a compilation fails?

Tags: terminal

I compile programs in my terminal and for a lengthy compilation, I usually let it sit in the background. I would like to be notified, somehow (maybe by sound), when the compilation fails. Is there a way to enable this feature?

Comment: Do you want any command that fails to produce a sound automatically? or do you want a special command you would add by hand to a command to be monitored? If the former, what is your shell? What is your terminal emulator? Do you work remotely (`ssh`)?

Comment: My Linux Mint (Ubuntu) has a text-to-speech tool (cannot recall if I had to install it). `spd-say "failed to make $target"`.

Comment: Would something as simple as `make || printf "\a"` work for you? This will beep once if the make fails.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do:

```
make || some-command-that-generates-some-sounds
```

Where `some-command-that-generates-some-sounds` could be `printf '\a'` which sends the BEL character upon which terminals usually emit a beep sound. Or some audio player with a pre-recorded sound (`play /path/to/some/audio/file` or `mplayer`/`aplay`...). Or some text to speech software with `say "make failed with exit code $?"`...

For some message to be issued any time a command failure is not handled, in some shells such as ksh, zsh or bash, you can also do something like:

```
trap 'say "some command failed with status $?"' ERR
```

(replace `say` with your text-to-speech command).